# Pervasive 9 - Export very large tables

Tags: sql-server-2005, pervasive

I'm looking for some guidance on exporting very large amounts of data for a migration project from pervasive 9 to a SQL databse.  By very large I'm talking row counts in excess of 10 million.

The throughput of import/export in ssis seems slow to me, so I'm wondering if anyone has domain experience with pervasive and has some performance tips.

Answer (score 0):

If you are exporting all of the records from a Pervasive database, you will be limited by how fast they can be read off disk and how much network latency there is.  MY best suggestion would be to run the export on the machine where Pervasive is running.  This will eliminate the network aspect of the equation.  With PSQL v9, and later, there is an Export wizard in the Pervasive Control Center.  It can export to CSV but you would have to export each table one at a time.  There are other third party tools (like my own [DataXtraction](http://www.mirtheil.com/dataxtraction.asp)) that can export all of the tables in a PSQL database.  I don't know if it would be any faster though.